# How to fix my Jekyll website from only loading locally

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll

I cloned and modified a [LogChimp](https://logchimp.now.sh/) Jekyll theme locally on my Windows 10 and pushed my changes to an online Github Pages repository titled "[Timeline](https://github.com/muygalan/timeline)".

I input `bundle exec jekyll serve` in my terminal and my website displays correctly locally. After I push my changes to my online repo, the [website does not display correctly](http://www.joshuagalan.com/timeline/) and is blank.

Here is my `config.yml` file:

```
title: Timeline – A Log of Life Events
url: http://www.joshuagalan.com/timeline
#logo: assets/img/logchimp.png
teams: true # Show team members
terminology: Changelog # By default we call this a changelog, but some might want to call it "release notes", or "changes" (Changelog, Release notes, Changes, Updates, News)

# Build settings
baseurl: /timeline/
theme: logchimp
permalink: /:title/

# Exclude from processing.
exclude:
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock
  - node_modules
  - vendor/bundle/
  - vendor/cache/
  - vendor/gems/
  - vendor/ruby/
  - .git
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jekyll theme is not supported on github pages ([see supported gems](https://pages.github.com/versions/)).

You can either pull generated pages to github in a different branch, or use another provider like [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/).